# Запуск программы через раз

Tags: c#, windows

Всем привет, сделал приложение Windows Form на с#. При запуске программа должна автоматически загружаться пр входе пользователя в систему. Проверять и обновлять ключ в реестре так, чтобы запускаться через раз. Идея состоит в том, что при загрузке операционной системы проверяется значение ключа реестра “key”. Если значение “key”- не ноль, то программа - не запускается и меняет значение “key” на 0, чтобы запуститься при следующем запуске. Если же“check”- ноль, то программа запускается. Вот примерный код, который просто должен менять значение ключа, но почему то не делает этого.

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Keys", true);
if (myKey != null)
{
    Application.Exit();
    myKey.SetValue("key", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    myKey.Close();
}
if (myKey == null)
{
    myKey.SetValue("key", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
    myKey.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Application.Exit();
> myKey.SetValue("key", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
> myKey.Close();
> ```

Поздно. Приложение уже закрылось, ничего никуда не запишется. Переставь строки.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим логику вашего кода:

1. `RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Keys", true);` - вы открываете раздел `Keys`, а он есть у вас? Я думаю, что нет..
2. `if (myKey != null)` - вы проверяете как раз, есть ли он у вас.
3. Допустим его нет (`else`) - вы пытаетесь записать в не существующий объект (то есть `NULL`) значение `key`. Получаете ошибку...

Ваш сначала надо создать раздел, если его нет, примерно так:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Keys", true);
if (myKey == null) myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Keys");
```

Далее уже, пытаться получить значение `Key` и изменить его:

```
var key = myKey?.GetValue("Key", 0);
if (key != null && (string) key == "0")
{
    myKey.SetValue("key", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
}
//else.....
```

Код написал примерный, но суть думаю ясна.